# Get footer to bottom of page bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I  have the following code in my bootstrap site in MVC C#. However I cannot get the footer to stick to the bottom.

```
  <footer class="main-footer" style="background: #3c8dbc; color: white; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
                <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                    <b>All rights reserved</b>
                </div>
                <strong>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a style="color:white;" href="http://example.com">zyz</a></strong> 
            </footer>
```

Can someone explain how to modify this code or any other code that will bring the footer to the bottom? Thanks.

Comment: What is inside the following class (main-footer)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jc0vtg53/ its working here.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with my theme's css overriding default bootstrap. Sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to modify a bit more CSS than just that of the footer, but 
here are 2 wonderful explanation of how to get the footer stick to the bottom - 
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the bodys min-height on 100% and the htmls height too.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body { 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```